# Turning a nonrigorous argument about finitely many set operations into a rigorous one

Tags: measure-theory

I have some issues with the following theorem:

Let $X$ be some nonempty set and let $H$ be a semiring on $X$ with
$X\in H$. Define $A$ as the family of sets obtained by forming finite
disjoint unions of sets from $H$. Then $A$ is the smallest algebra
containing $H$.

The proof goes as follows: First we show that $A$ is an algebra.
No problems here. But then the argument for $A$ being the smallest
algebra containing $H$ goes as follows:

Since each element of $A$ is obtained by applying finitely many set-theoretic
operations on sets of $H$, $A$ has to be the smallest algebra containing
$H$.

This is not rigorous enough for me! Could you help me turn this into
a rigorous argument ?

Comment: Merely observe that every member of $A$ must belong to any algebra containing $H$. At worst that's a proof by induction on the number of sets in the union.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please be a little more explicit concerning the last sentence of yours ?

Comment: If $h_1,h_2\in H$ with $h_1\cap h_2=\varnothing$, then we must have $h_1\cup h_2\in A$. Suppose that we know this to be the case for unions of disjoint families of $n$ sets from $H$, and let $\{h_1,\ldots,h_{n+1}\}$ be a disjoint family of $n+1$ sets from $H$. Then $h_1\cup\ldots\cup h_{n+1}=a\cup h_{n+1}$, where $a=h_1\cup\ldots\cup h_n$, and we must have $a\cup h_{n+1}\in A$.